# Python's not() Function not a Normal Function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I know python has the not operator, but how does the not() function come into play?

From some simple testing it appears that it has the signature of not(args[]), while at the same time not acting entirely like a normal function. For example:

```py
x = True
not x # -> False
not(x) # -> False
x = False
not x # -> True
not(x) # -> True

not(0) # -> True
not(1) # -> False
not(0, 0, 0) # -> False
not("False") # -> False

function = not # -> Syntax Error
```

Why does this exist for "not", and not something like "or"? Is there a way I can capture the not function into a variable / do other manipulation with not as a function?

This question was mostly prompted by attempting to find a single function to invert a list in a map call, even if it is an internal function

Comment: Spoiler alert: there is no `not` function

Comment: Who told to you that ``not`` is a function. Dont you see the color of that word in your IDE? Or why you are not try ``type(not)``?

Comment: A  unary operator (like `not`) applied to a parenthesized expression may *look* like a function call, but it is not.

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL Not everyone uses an IDE with syntax highlighting, or the highlighting in use may not differentiate between functions and operators, and `type(not)` would produce a syntax error just like `function = not`, so that wouldn't really provide any new information.

Comment: @chepner You may be right about IDE topic. And I mean that Syntax Error too. Because it is a keyword, not an object.

Comment: What should be done with this question?

Comment: It is not a genuine question? A bit misguided and so deep in looking for a solution I mixed up my understanding, but is this not something someone else might run into? Clearly I made this mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `not` function. There is only the operator `not`. Adding parentheses is just adding parentheses around the expression; It is not a function call (i.e. `not(x)` is exactly the same thing as `not x`). `not(0,0,0)` is just the `not` operator applied to the tuple `(0,0,0)`, which isn’t "falsey" so the result is false.

(Note that this is the situation in Python specifically, other languages may have `not` as a function or some other way to express `not` entirely).

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL [No, I meant what I wrote](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/109996/is-it-falsy-or-falsey).

Comment: To be clearer, the parentheses are part of the expression that the operator is applied to, not function-call syntax.

Comment: That still seems odd as most statements within python do not work with something immediately attached to them. For example or(1) would not work

Comment: `or` isn't a unary operator; it's a binary operator. `(a) or (b)` would work just fine, with the two parenthesized expressions `(a)` and `(b)`. `or(1)` not working has nothing to do with the parentheses.

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL It’s not even bad english, "falsey" and "truthy" are words that are really only used this way in CS as far as I know; It’s just slightly odd language because we needed some words to distinguish the property of "being true" from "being exactly the literal value true" (and equivalent for false).

Comment: Okay cool. I've probably gotten a bit too lost trying to find a single function call to invert a list within a map call. Definitely makes sense though since the not operator is applied to a single item, rather than multiple items. The syntax also makes sense, though it seems off at first glance. It probably makes a bit more sense to look at it like the "~" operator

Answer (score 2):

There is no `not` function. Adding parentheses is totally redundant here, it's not a function call:

```
 >>> (1) == 1
True
>>> dis.dis('not(1)')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 UNARY_NOT
              4 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('not 1')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 UNARY_NOT
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can build a function of course `def f(x): return not x` but you can probably just use inverse truthy function(s), i.e. `bool()` or `operator.truth()`

Comment: Also ``not(0, 0, 0)`` creates a tuple.

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL `(0, 0, 0)` creates a tuple, yes of course- what's your point?

Comment: `not` has nothing to do with creating the tuple. The commas do that, but `not` has a higher precedence, so the parentheses allow you to apply `not` to the tuple `0, 0, 0`, rather than creating the tuple `True, 0, 0` (with `not` being applied to the first 0 first).

Comment: @Chris_Rands I mean a tuple which has atleast one element will be ``true`` as a boolean.

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL yes, i know, most objects are truthy apart from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/6260170

Answer (score 1):

not is a keyword not an object. So you can't set it to variable.

List of Python keywords https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keywo

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said, there is no such thing as a negation function like it would be the case in other languages like Julia.

> This question was mostly prompted by attempting to find a single function to invert a list in a map call, even if it is an internal function

If you want to a negate a list of booleans using a `map` call, you can simply use a `lambda` like this:

```py
>>> mask = [True, False, True]
>>> list(map(lambda b: not b, mask))
[False, True, False]
```

Alternatively, you can apply Python's bitwise NOT `~` to a `numpy` array:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mask = np.array([True, False, True])
>>> ~mask
array([False, True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Note that I used `~` instead of `not`. Logical operators are indeed not supported on numpy arrays so writing `not mask` would produce the following error:

```py
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Hope this can help someone!